# Fitting an image to a container on all pages except one

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Thank you for helping me out. I am not the main developer on this project but have been thrust into the role as our backend dev is busy with more prudent tasks.

The site we are working on has a number of pages that open with an image that fits the window: the homepage, gallery and locations pages are all worked into this with some jquery. The client requested us to change the layout of the locations page so it is no longer fitting to the window, but instead a little shorter than window height (for argument sake lets say 400px shorter).

I have located the jquery in question along with the snippet of code we need to edit. I also believe we can use the class .locationHero to specify a change to the header on the Locations page.

How can I adjust the code below so that the hero on the Locations page is 400px shorter than window height?

```
function onresize (){
    if ($(window).width() >= 1024) {

        var originalHeight =$(window).height() - 154;

        $('section#homeBoxes').css({'height':originalHeight});

        var changeElements = $('.fullViewPort');

        changeElements.each(function(){

            var windowHeight = originalHeight;

            if ($(this).hasClass('galleryWrapper')) {
                windowHeight = windowHeight - 40;
            } else {
                windowHeight = originalHeight;
            }

            if ($(this).is('.template-menus, .about, .featuredEvent, .private-events, .press')) {
                windowHeight = windowHeight / 2;
            } else {
                windowHeight = originalHeight;
            }

            // Set a minimum to avoid things getting crushed
            if (windowHeight < 460) {
                windowHeight = 475;
            };

            $(this).css({'height':windowHeight});
        });

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well that was easy. I just added the . locationHero to the area:

```
 if ($(this).is('.template-menus, .about, .featuredEvent, .private-events, .press')) {
            windowHeight = windowHeight / 2;
        } else {
            windowHeight = originalHeight;
        }
```